# Efficiently check if elements lie between closed intervals

Tags: python, loops, intervals

I have a tuple x with elements as `x = (2, 3, 4, 5)`. I also have another data structure that holds closed intervals with the number of elements **equal to the number of elements in the tuple x**, as `y = ((2,3), (3.5, 4.5), (6, 9), (4, 7))`.

Now, I can set up a nested loop and check if each element of x lies within the respective intervals in y. But the issue is that it takes too long for a tuple with 10000 elements. Although efficiency might not matter, I do want the code to run fast.

> Note: By efficient I do mean time wise, where the code runs faster than any other 'obvious' solutions.

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this using Python instead of the obvious nested loop? This seems to be only possible with the nested loops solution.

I don't have any code as I can not figure the question out. If I could have hints as to how to make it efficient then please provide them.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried. We can't tell you a "more" efficient way without something to compare with.

Comment: By efficient, do you mean time wise, memory wise, or cleanliness of code? Also, will you be changing the tuples? Do you want to be able to check multiple times?

Comment: Efficiency depends on _given reference code_ for "nested loop" and how it performs the "check". The "more" depends on the "obvious" that you show us by [example]. Please [edit] and give us this reference code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this

```
>>> x = (2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> y = ((2,3), (3.5, 4.5), (6, 9), (4, 7))
>>> def f(e):
...     p, (q, r) = e
...     return q <= p  <= r
>>> list(map(f, zip(x,y)))
[True, False, False, True]
```

Comment: What if you made the function print all of the outputs and not one? I like the idea.

Comment: The OP mentions "10000 elements", it's not very practical to print 10K items

Comment: Sorry, not print, but return.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Although this is definitely not efficient for a small tuple, for a large one this will speed up the process greatly (from an O(n^2) solution to an O(n)). I hope this helps.

```py
x = (2, 3, 4, 5)
y = ((2, 3), (3.5, 4.5), (6, 9), (4, 7))
for a, b in enumerate(y):
    if b[0] <= x[a] <= b[1]:
        print(f'{x[a]} is in between {b}.')
    else:
        print(f'{x[a]} is not in between {b}')
```

For boolean values:

```py
interval = lambda t, i: [b[0] <= t[a] <= b[1] for a, b in enumerate(i)]
x = (2, 3, 4, 5)
y = ((2, 3), (3.5, 4.5), (6, 9), (4, 7))
print(interval(x, y))
```

All within linear (O(n)) time! Thanks for reading and have a great day.

Comment: This just works for `len(x) == len(y)`

Comment: With the limited detail from the question, his "test case" has the same length, but if you wanted to do otherwise it would be as simple as switching the enumerate and the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in linear time using one loop.
You only have to iterate once on both of the tuples, something like this:

```py
x = (2, 3, 4, 5)
y = ((2,3), (3.5, 4.5), (6, 9), (4, 7))
 
 
for index, number in enumerate(x):
    if number > y[index][1] or number < y[index][0]:
         print(f'{number} is NOT in {y[index}')
    else:
        print(f'{number} is in {y[index]}')
```

the output is:

> 2 is in the interval (2, 3) 
> 3 is NOT in the interval (3.5, 4.5) 
> 4 is NOT in the interval (6, 9) 
> 5 is in the interval (4, 7)

As i said, this solution will take O(n), instead of O(n^2)